# BSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions always get public_pofile only

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios7, xcode5

Hi Guys i want to share on facebook , when user is not login in I ask from login/permissions in following way

```
   [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"status_update",nil]
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
             NSLog(@"Login failed");
         else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
             [self PostOnWall];
     }];
};
```

In permission dailogs it always ask for just public profile and when I am trying to share some thing it shows following error

```
              Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x16d40d20 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 200;
        message = "(#200) Permissions error";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 403;
 },
```

Please help why its not asking for proper permissions

Comment: Did you find out solution ??
I have same problem now... X(

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. FB bug perhaps? I have the latest SDK installed. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I think I found the issue. You'll need update your FB app and submit for approval the additional permissions you need ("publish_actions"). If you don't do this, then only Facebook users listed in your app's roles will have extended permissions without FB approval

[image]